# Dictionary attack

Tags: security

Is it possible to download a list of the common words used in a dictionary attack?

Or am I looking at this problem wrongly?

Comment: What asset are you trying to attack? Passwords? Path/file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Sipvicious**](http://code.google.com/p/sipvicious/wiki/WordLists) has links to some excellent wordlists. Suitable for analysis or for running your own assessments.

Answer (score 1):

The password cracker [John The Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) provides a common passwords list. If you use this list and append any regular english dictionary list you have a good start.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a dictionary db that you can use. But why not to write your own service which gets the possible words from translation and encyclopedia services? You could then provide your service to others.